# How can I loop through all the rows of a Spark dataframe and apply a function to each row?

Tags: loops, apache-spark, dataframe

I need to loop through all the rows of a Spark dataframe and use the values in each row as inputs for a function.

Basically, I want this to happen:

1. Get row of database
2. Separate the values in the database's row into different variables
3. Use those variables as inputs for a function I defined

The thing is, I can't use `collect()` because the dataframe is too big.

I am pretty sure I have to use `map()` to perform what I want and I have tried doing this:

```
MyDF.rdd.map(MyFunction)
```

But how can I specify the information I want to retrieve from the DataFrame? Something like Row(0), Row(1) and Row(2)?

And how do I "feed" those values to my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Looping" is not what you really want, but a "projection". If for example your dataframe has 2 fields of type int and string, your code would look like this:

```
val myFunction = (i:Int,s:String) =>  ??? // do something with the variables

df.rdd.map(row => myFunction(row.getAs[Int]("field1"), row.getAs[String]("field2")))
```

or with pattern matching :

```
df.rdd.map{case Row(field1:Int, field2:String) => myFunction(field1,field2)}
```

Note that in Spark 2, you can directly use `map` on your dataframe and get a new dataframe (in spark 1.6 `map` would result in a `RDD` instead).

Note that instead of using `map` in `RDD` you could also use an "User Defined Function" (UDF) in the dataframe API